# Multi Picklist Custom Formula Field Get First Group

Tags: custom-field

On the contact object, a contact can be grouped into multiple groups through a native multi-picklist field. I want a custom field that should pick out the first group in the group field. For example, someone could be grouped as both "Assistant; Business". I want the custom field to pick out the "Assistant" group.

What is the custom field formula I could use?

Before, I did this:

```
TRIM(
     LEFT(
           MtgPlanner_CRM__Group__c , FIND(";", MtgPlanner_CRM__Group__c) -1
         )
     )
```

However, I get the error on validation:

> Error: Field `MtgPlanner_CRM__Group__c` is a multi-select picklist
>   field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain
>   functions.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

as per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5)  Multi-select picklist fields can only be used in these functions `INCLUDES`,`ISBLANK`,`ISNULL` you can not use `FIND` function. if your multi picklist field have limited no of values you can achieve by using `INCLUDES` if you want to stick to a formula... you are stuck with the `IF-INCLUDES` for each option.

You could alternative consider making a very simple trigger on before insert and before update on your parent object.